# Bootstrap icon in the middle of a circular button of custom height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="border-radius:50%;margin-left:10px;
margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;height:30px;width:30px;">

         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </span>

  </button>
```

I want a circular button with a plus sign inside it. But the problem is that the plus sign doesn't align itself in the middle of the button. Any solution of it? I have to maintain the height (30px), because the button will actually be in a table row with other elements. Like this:
[image]

Here the plus sign doesn't appear in the middle. I need a solution to this problem.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1yvhhc2/

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet to see your problem?

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x1yvhhc2/ @VadimOvchinnikov

Comment: try `padding:0px` for the button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply `absolute` position to the `span` and center it.

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="border-radius:50%;margin-left:10px;
margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;height:30px;width:30px;">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </span>
  </button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by flexbox:

```css
.some-button {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-center-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* center horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* center vertically */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info some-button">
  <div class="flex-center-wrapper">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </div>
</button>
```